# How can I reject mails coming from a fake domain or a fake user in a real domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010, email-server, spoofing

I have an exchange server 2010 recently installed and I receive a test with 3 step to check the security of my server. below the test

1. Check if my server receive from fake domain.
2. Check if my server receive from fake user in real domain.
3. impersonate identity in my domain.

the 1 and 2 test was successfully passed with no configuration in exchange, but the third fails, in my research someone recommend me to use an spf record in the DNS to fix 3. I put the following record:

```
something.co.cu IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:<ip address> -all"
```

in the dns and fix the 3 test but 1 and 2 now fail and i don't know why. I am new in this world.